# Maintaining History Stack for SPA based web applications

Tags: html, single-page-application

How to handle History stacks while working with SPA based web applications? I can have my custom stack to track the pages visited, but since I'm just hiding/showing `div`s , and manipulating the 'history' object requires to push in URLs, I'm unable to understand how to go about handling the situation?

The URL will always remaining something like this : `http://mywebapplication/#`
I can't push any URLs into the `history` stack because for all `div`s being shown, the URL remains the same. Even if I'm somehow able to achieve the same, I don't think overriding the back button of browser should be considered a good practice?

Please suggest how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to track your browsed divs you need some sort of routing solution. You can use [Crossroads](http://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/) to register and manage your routes. Each route should have a handler, which enables the appropriate div in your single page.

```
var route1 = crossroads.addRoute('/page1/', function(id){
  //enable div for page1 route
});
```

Then, you can use [Hasher](http://github.com/millermedeiros/hasher/) to manage browser history.